# Angular 2 typescript: Cannot read property newLine of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am using angular-CLI for angular 2, for running I am doing ng serve in command prompt after ng serve getting module build failed  'Cannot read property newLine of undefined' error for all my angular 2 projects.

```
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
at Object.getNewLineCharacter (C:\Users\timebound\angularJson\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8062:20)
at Object.createCompilerHost (C:\Users\timebound\angularJson\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44978:26)
at Object.ngcLoader (C:\Users\timebound\angularJson\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:329:31)
```

@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4300/ ./src/main.ts

I followed [angular cli issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3781),still i am not able to fix, i am newer to angular 2, please help me

Comment: Please try to elaborate your question. We can't help you if aren't specific.

Comment: Had the same issue even after following angular cli upgrade instructions, removing node_modes folder in my app solved it..

Comment: @frant.hartm Thanks, i had solevd it by running through npm start instead of  doing ng serve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the devDependencies from `"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3"` to `"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.30"`

Comment: Hi, I tried installed with @latest and still stuck on `28.3` how did you get `.30` to download? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419964/module-build-failed-typeerror-cannot-read-property-newline-of-undefined