# npm update --save producing error and block the run of ng serve

Tags: angular-cli, angular

I am running the `npm update --save` and there after running my angular cli project It producing the following error

```
ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/home/nifras/Documents/web-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:9514:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/home/nifras/Documents/web-cli/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:63770:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/home/nifras/Documents/web-cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:329:31)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I could not able to figure-out the error. In my assuming the error is producing version unmet of typescript. How to fix this error

I have added the package.json and angular-cli.json on bellow

### package.json

```
    {
  "name": "coral-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.10",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.65",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.1",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10",
    "codelyzer": "^2.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "gentelella": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-loading-bar": "0.0.6",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^2.4.0",
    "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.46",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.0-beta.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.0.4"
  }
}
```

### angualr-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "name": "coral-web"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/vendors/skycons/skycons.js",
        "../node_modules/gentelella/build/js/custom.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May be this link help you.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128715/angular-2-typescript-cannot-read-property-newline-of-undefined)

Comment: It produce another set of errors of unment dependecy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but maybe someone else will stumble over this again.

Regarding your angular-cli.json you are comming from a cli beta version less  than beta.28, so just npm update won't be  enough.

Update angualr cli like explained in the
[official wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update).

> If you're using Angular CLI beta.28 or less, you need to uninstall the
>   angular-cli package.
>
> `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
>
> `npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli`
>
> To update Angular CLI to a new version, you must update both the global
>   package and your project's local package.
>
> Global package:
>
> ```
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
> npm cache clean
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
> ```
>
> Local project package:
>
> ```
> rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir on Windows
> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
> npm install
> ```